# How to get alternate and much improved code for this colour checking function please

Tags: python, list, pygame

I am learning python and am attempting the game of Mastermind using pygame.  I have defined a function that checks for the colour of the pixel under the mouse pointer when clicked thus;

```
def colour_check_under_mouse():
 mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
    colour_under_mouse = pygame.Surface.get_at(screen, mouse_pos)
    print(colour_under_mouse)
    if colour_under_mouse[0] == 255 and colour_under_mouse[1] == 255:
        print('Yellow')
    elif colour_under_mouse[0] == 255:
        print('red')
    elif colour_under_mouse[1] == 255:
        print('Green')
    elif colour_under_mouse[2] == 255:
        print('Blue')
```

`colour_under_mouse` contains a list of (red, green, blue, alpha) and I simply use if statements to check for those specific colours under the mouse pointer.  I have as yet not coded the logic for what I do with the results hence using the print statements.

I appreciate there is plenty of opportunity for errors here, but at the moment as I am learning, it works.  I am also sure though that there is a far more efficient way to code this rather than the cumbersome use of several elif statements, but given my limited knowledge of coding, syntax etc - I am unaware of how I can do this.  Could someone offer some advice please.  Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you're getting `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]`. Are you sure there's always going to be data returned? What if you do `[0]` but there's no data? Also your if statements you can compare two arrays/tuples directly. `if colour_under_mouse == (255, 255, 0)` will check if it's yellow and so on. You even store the colors in a dictionary and `dict_obj[colour_under_mouse]` and it will give you the color, given that you initially store the colors in the dict, such as `dict_obj[(255, 0, 0)] = "Red"`

Comment: Brilliant advice there @thethiny, thank you!  Yes, the get.pressed[0] looks for the left button press, and it is the manner I am using to get user input on which colour to select for their 'go'.  They simply click on one of four colour circles, four times - to get their full 'go', and these are always on a static part of the board.  Also, I have used a dict initially to define the colours associated with the random numbers generated at the start of the game - so knowing I can check the array/tuple in a single if is pure gold knowledge to me.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @thethiny [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) always returns data. Please read the documentation.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm unfamiliar with this library and I won't read the documentation for it since I have no time to invest in it. Thank you though for clearing my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

solution 1 (the boring one):

as already suggested in the comments you can use a dictionary for comparison:

```
colors = {
    (0, 0, 0): 'black',
    (255, 0, 0): 'red',
    ...
}

# in the if clicked section:
if color_under_mouse in colors:  # first check if the color is in the dict
    print(colors[color_under_mouse])
```

solution 2 (the awesome one):

use python3.10 new pattern matching feature:

```
# in the if clicked section:
match tuple(color_under_mouse)[:3]  # this may work with just `color_under_mouse` as well.
    case (0, 0, 0):
        print('black')
    case (255, 0, 0):
        print('red')
    # you can do even more complex things:
    case (0, 0, x):
        print('a blue gradient')
    case (255, 255, x) if x < 150:
        print('a yellow tone')
    # even stuff like this:
    case (a, b, c) if sum(a, b, c) > 600 and c > a > b:
        print('light blue-ish purple')
```